# Jasypt Spring EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer not reading VM arguments

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jasypt

Ever since I replaced Spring's PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with Jasypt's EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, I've not been able to read the VM arguments passed to the application (eg: -DtestVar=testVal) through @Value annotations. The properties from app.properties file is being read and/or decrypted as expected. But the VM arguments are just not read. It is supposed to override the properties on app.properties with the value passed as VM argument.

What the config used to be (when VM arguments were being read and working as expected):

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer myConfig() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

My current Jasypt EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer config looks like this, which replaced the above:

```
@Bean
public static PooledPBEStringEncryptor configuEncryptor() {
    PooledPBEStringEncryptor configuEncryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
    configuEncryptor.setConfig(environmentVariableConfig());
    return configuEncryptor;
}

@Bean
public static EnvironmentStringPBEConfig environmentVariableConfig() {
    final EnvironmentStringPBEConfig config = new EnvironmentStringPBEConfig();
    config.setAlgorithm(ALGORITHM);
    config.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    return config;
}

@Bean
public static EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(configuEncryptor());
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(
            new ClassPathResource("app.properties")
    );
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

There were no issues reading externally passed VM arguments(which overrides props in app.properties) when Spring's PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer was being used. This has become an issue after implementing Jasypt's EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Have anyone been able to solve this?